# Http get request using axios in react.js

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Temp.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
const Temp=()=> {
    const APP_ID='8232312'
    const APP_KEY='6a4e7c08d71463dada3b481f85a9b16'
    const [receipe, setReceipe] = useState([])


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use effect")
axios.get(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`)
        .then(response => {
          console.log('get receipe by promise', response)
          console.log("use state variable receipes")
          setReceipe(response.data)
          console.log("after use state receipe = " , receipe)
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e))


    });

    return (

        <div>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Temp
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Temp from './Component/Temp';

const App = ()=> {

  return (
<div className='App'> 
<Temp></Temp>
</div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Console output-

```
use effect
Temp.js:13 get receipe by promise {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
Temp.js:14 use state variable receipes
Temp.js:16 after use state receipe =  []
Temp.js:10 use effect
Temp.js:13 get receipe by promise {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
Temp.js:14 use state variable receipes
Temp.js:16 after use state receipe =  {q: "chicken", from: 0, to: 10, more: true, count: 168106, …}
Temp.js:10 use effect
Temp.js:13 get receipe by promise {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
Temp.js:14 use state variable receipes
Temp.js:16 after use state receipe =  {q: "chicken", from: 0, to: 10, more: true, count: 168106, …}
Temp.js:10 use effect
Temp.js:13 get receipe by promise {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
Temp.js:14 use state variable receipes
Temp.js:16 after use state receipe =  {q: "chicken", from: 0, to: 10, more: true, count: 168106, …}
```

in the console output, for the first time, the recipe is set to empty while the second-time recipe is set with the response from the HTTP request. But I need setReceipe(response.data) to set receipe to response.data for first time also

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

You cannot and should not even try to. On first load, you do not even have the data to populate your state. Hence, you cannot do that.

**Long Answer**

HTTP Network calls (`axios GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` or any other network call using any other library) are asynchronous. When you load your component (application), `XHR` calls are placed in queue to be executed. During this time your UI renders and your `state` is initialized to some default value. Once the `XHR` call is completetd successfully, then actually you receive the data from server. Now you can update your state with `response.data`.

Also, do not worry about this behavior. This is common for any application in place practically.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## It's not possible

The render and rerender happen one after the other. The receiving of the data takes time and so your initial data will be empty.

### Quick fix

A way to stop this breaking is to make sure that you have a default value, like you already have.

```
const [receipe, setReceipe] = useState([])
...
receipe.map((item) => <p>{item.someText}</p>)
```

If recipe is defaulted to `[]` or if its filled with data `[{someText: 'text'}]` the map over data will not break. You can also choose to not render the component if there's no data

```
return recipe ? <Component /> : null
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below example that how you can call api with GET request using axios:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function PostListPage() {
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    let signal = axios.CancelToken.source();

    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
            cancelToken: signal.token,
        })
            .then(res => {
                const posts = res.data;
                setPost(posts);
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        return function cleanup() {
            isSubscribed = false;
            signal.cancel('Api is being canceled');
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default PostListPage;
```